# preg_match not working with php variable

Tags: php, drupal, preg-match

preg_match is not working with dynamic php variable.

```
if ( preg_match( '/abc.com|xyz.com\b/', $m[0] ) ) {
```

Above match is working fine but when I am sending values using PHP variable then it is not working

```
$string = 'abc.com|xyz.com';
if ( preg_match( '/'.$string.'\b/', $m[0] ) ) {
```

I am sending same value in $string variable but it is still not working. Please help.

Comment: Should work exactly the same. Please give us a [mcve]. Also do you know that `.` means match any character? And `|` is for alternatives?

Comment: whats the value of `$m[0]` ???

Comment: $m[0] has full content of a story.. I want to remove all links from story.. but want to retain a few..

Comment: `if ( preg_match( '/abc.com|xyz.com\b/', $m[0] ) ) { // do not remove links
    return $m[0];
   } else { // remove links
    return preg_replace( '/\<a(.*)\>(.*)\<\/a\>/iU', '$2', $m[0]);
   }`

Comment: If preg_match false (else case) what you will be replace ?

Comment: then I am just removing anchor links around text

Comment: Trust me, strings don't have memory. PHP doesn't know or care how you composed `$m[0]`. If your code doesn't work with a variable it's because it doesn't work with literal input (but you probably didn't verify it and assumed the former).

Comment: I agree with you friend.. but I tested it using a plain string too.. its working absltly fine when I am writing it static but when I am sending it dynamic its not working as expected.. tested it many times using different syntax.. I am adding a filter in wordpress. Its strange but its happening

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me now.
As I was using it inside preg_replace_callback
So have to declare it inside it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the `preg_replace_callback`, the issue is most probably with the fact that you need to pass the variable to the function with `use` keyword.

See below [PHP snippet](https://ideone.com/Du6mei) showing that:

```
$string = 'abc\.com|xyz\.com';
$s  = "Some long string with http:". "//sub.abc.com inside";
$res = preg_replace_callback('~http://\S+~', function ($m) use ($string) {
    if (preg_match('/\b(?:'.$string.')\b/', $m[0])) {
        return "GOOD_URL";
    } else {
        return "BAD_URL";
    }
}, $s);
echo $res;
```

Note that the dots inside the regex pattern must be escaped.